# How to stretch product's rows to maximum?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I work on Nuxt.js (Vue.js) application that uses BootstrapVue (Bootstrap based) package.

The current situation is as following:

[image]

[image]

The code looks as following:

```
<template lang="pug">
  b-container
    b-row
      b-col(:cols="8")
        b-container
          b-row
            b-list-group
              b-list-group-item.flex-column.align-items-start(
                v-for="(item, index) in 7" :key="index"
                href='#'
              )
                b-container
                  b-row
                    b-col(:cols="1").d-flex.align-items-center.justify-content-center
                      b-form-checkbox {{ index + 1 }}
                    b-col(:cols="11")
                      basket-item(:itemNumber="index + 1" :checkStatus="accepted")
          b-row.style-row-middle
            b-button.close(type='button' aria-label='Close' @click="onClose()")
              span(aria-hidden='true') &times;
                u Удалить выбранное
            b-button(type='button' @click="onContinue()").btn.btn-lg.buy__button Продолжить покупки
          b-row
            div
              hr
              | * доставка будет осуществлена из Санкт-Петербурга;
              br
              | * наш менеджер свяжется с вами сразу после обработки заказа;
      b-col(:cols="4" class="col2")
        form(ref='form' @submit.stop.prevent='handleSubmit').set-padding
          div
            strong
              label ЗАКАЗ
          div
            strong
              label Всего товаров: 1
          div
            strong
              label На суму: 100 000 р
          b-form-group(label='')
          b-form-group(label='Телефон' label-for='type-tel' invalid-feedback='Phone is required')
            b-form-input(id="type-tel" type="tel" v-model='phone' required)
          b-form-group(label='E-mail' label-for='type-email' invalid-feedback='E-mail is required')
            b-form-input(id="type-email" type="email" v-model='email' required)
          b-form-group(label='Ваше имя' label-for='name-input' invalid-feedback='Name is required' :state='nameState')
            b-form-input(:id="name-input" v-model='name' :state='nameState')

          div.d-flex.align-items-center.justify-content-center
            b-button(type='submit' variant='primary' size="lg") Оформить заказ
</template>

<style lang="sass">
.list-group
  margin-bottom: 10px
  max-height: 400px
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
  overflow-y: auto
.list-group-item
  border-style: none
.set-padding
  padding-bottom: 7px
  padding-top: 7px
.style-row
  border: solid 1px black
  display: flex
  justify-content: space-between
.style-row-middle
  display: flex
  justify-content: space-between
  padding: 4px
.col1
  border: 1px solid red
.col2
  border: 10px solid rgb(0, 70, 140)
.buy__button
  background-color: #eee
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #ccc 0%, #eee 100%)
  border: 1px solid #cccccc
  color: black
  font-size: 16px
  text-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 0 white
.set-border
  border: 1px solid gray
  border-radius: 3px
  margin-bottom: 2px
  margin-top: 2px
</style>
```

I need to stretch product's rows to maximum, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: reduce or remove the x padding, i.e `b-list-group-item.flex-column.align-items-start.px-0(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot shows padding in `.list-group-item` that could be reduced to `2px`:

```css
.list-group-item
  padding: 2px
```

Also, `.list-group` should take the full width available in the row:

```css
.list-group
  width: 100%
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/setting-list-group-row-width-bvzuu?file=/src/components/MyList.vue:2468-2643)